# How do you log an uncaught exception in Java?

Tags: java, swing, exception, testing

My client is testing my beta phase Java application on a data that he cannot provide me with (privacy reasons). Although I implemented the handling of most exceptions, application crashes on rare occasions.

Can I log the stacktrace of an uncaught exception to a file so that tester can provide me with it(e.g. `NullPointerException`)?

Comment: @Quoi Sorry but I'm pretty new user and so far answers to my questions were not solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) that prints to the specified file.

Answer (score 0):

If the main thread crashes, the JVM will print a stacktrace automatically.

For other threads, you can use [setUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the thing what [`UncaughtExceptionHandler` concept is about](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

Basically you are able to register a piece of code to be executed when the exception reaches the top of the stack.